# jekyll 2.0.3 Error: undefined method `pygments_prefix' for #<Jekyll::Converters::Identity>

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to `jekyll serve` a website that was created with a previous version of jekyll.

I had to update my `_config.yml` file from this:

```
#Build settings
markdown: rdiscount
pygments: true
paginate: 100
permalink: pretty
```

To this:

```
#Build settings
markdown: rdiscount
highlighter: pygments
paginate: 100
permalink: pretty
```

This should be OK but I get the following error when I try to `serve` the application.

```
jekyll 2.0.3 Error:  undefined method `pygments_prefix' for #<Jekyll::Converters::Identity>`
```

Any help on that? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my experience with the very same problem, this function and its `suffix' sibling have been renamed to *highlighter_prefix* and *highlighter_suffix* in Jekyll 2.0.3.

This is probably caused by one of your plugins, grep them out and replace them and things might just work.

Good luck!

Comment: It was indeed one of my plugins. Specifically, the 'jekyll-localization'.